# Reading a complex XML file in C# (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm having big trouble reading an XML Document with c# in Unity.
The XML I'm trying to read has a structure like this:

```
<Classes A>
 <Class A></Class A>
 <Class A></Class A>
  <Class A></Class A>
   <Class A>
    <Detail X>
    <Detail Y>
   </Class A>
   <Class A>
   (...)
```

Sometimes, Class A has children; sometimes, Class A is a child of another Class A etc.

I've been trying and researching for 2 days, however I can't manage to understand how to read this using System.XML or System.XML.Linq

I'm able to read all the Elements and their Attributes using XDocument.Read(), however I'm not able to get any information on whether they're inherited by another class or have children themselves.
How can I read an Element and then have it check whether there are any children and if

a) there are children, continue to read the children

or

b) there are no children, continue to read the next Element.

I understand that XNodes presumably contain the information I want. I'm able to read all of the XNodes, too. But I'm not able to cast any XNode to an XElement or vice versa. None of the functions behave as I'd expect.

Comment: A nested xml like this you should read it using a recursive algorithm.  Don't it lots of time before.  With recursion I like making a class object to contain each node.  The code is real simple and take me less than 10 minute to create.

Comment: I'm currently looking into what a recursive algorithm is. However, I think your answer is still not precise enough for me to understand. If I have all the Nodes at my disposal (I know how to get the XNodes) then what would I do with them? As far as my research goes, it's not possible to get i.e. the name of an element contained in an XNode. There are no functions for that.

Comment: Post a VALID xml and I will help.  Make sure no error.  Check xml using VS.  From menu : Project : Add New Item : XML.  The paste your xml into view.  Errors will be in the Error List just like any compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Classes A="1">
  <Class A="1.1"/>
  <Class A="1.2">
    <Detail X="1.2.1"/>
  </Class>
  <Class A="1.3">
    <Detail X="1.3.1"/>
    <Detail Y="1.3.2"/>
  </Class>
  <Class A="1.4"/>
</Classes>
```

C# Code

```
        public void XMLToTreeView()
        {
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Path\Sample.xml");
            var xElement = XElement.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            findAllNodes(xElement, treeView1);
        }

        private void findAllNodes(XElement xElement, TreeView treeView)
        {
            TreeNode ParentNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(xElement.Attributes().FirstOrDefault().Value);
            foreach (XElement childElement in xElement.Elements())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                node.Text = childElement.Attributes().FirstOrDefault().Value;
                ParentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
                findAllNodes(childElement, node);
            }
        }

        private void findAllNodes(XElement xElement, TreeNode node)
        {
            foreach (XElement childElement in xElement.Elements())
            {
                TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
                childNode.Text = childElement.Attributes().FirstOrDefault().Value;
                node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                findAllNodes(childElement, childNode);
            }
        }
```

[image]